# C++ input file isn't reading my whole file back in to string

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a program that is taking in a JSON file, of approx 170,000 characters total. I am saving them all to a text file (this part works fine) and then I am trying to read that entire text file back into a string:

```
json::value historicalData = value;
    ofstream outputFile("test.txt"); //output to file
    outputFile << historicalData; //store JSON into file
    ifstream inputFile("test.txt"); //input from file
    string historicalDataString="";
    string appendTemp;
    while(!inputFile.eof()){
    getline(inputFile,appendTemp); //store value from file into string
    historicalDataString.append(appendTemp);
    }
```

When I use this code above to read the file back in, I do not get the entire length of the file back. It stops about two thirds of the way, and is appending a "1" onto the end of my string. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Close `outputFile` before reading. Some data is probably still sitting in its buffers.

Comment: Welp. I feel dumb, but that did it, thanks!

Comment: Read [Why is `iostream::eof` inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: There are better ways to read a file into a `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

```
outputFile.close();
```

Solved my issues.

Comment: You can click the check mark next to this answer to mark the question as resolved